# Graphql: Query returns null for all fields except ID

Tags: javascript, database, graphql, relay

When I run the following Query:

```
{
  viewer {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

I get the following object which displays the incorrect query results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "id": "VXNlcjo=",
      "firstName": null,
      "lastName": null
    }
  }
}
```

I have set up the following database.js:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

// Create a Sequelize instance
var connection = new Sequelize('dev', 'mary', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
});

// User model
var User = connection.define('user', {
  // First name
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      is: {
        args: /^[a-z]+$/i,
        msg: 'First name is invalid'
      }
    }
  },
  // Last name
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      is: {
        args: /^[a-z]+$/i,
        msg: 'Last name is invalid'
      }
    }
  },
  // Username
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      is: {
        args: /^@?(\w){3,15}$/,
        msg: 'Username can not exceed 15 characters or contain spaces.'
      }
    }
  },
  // Email
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      isEmail: true
    }
  },
  // Password
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      // Validate Password
    }
  }
}, {
  // Use plural names in database.
  freezeTableName: false,
  // Timestamps
  timestamps: true,
  // hooks
  hooks: {
    afterValidate: user => {
      user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 8);
    }
  }
});

// Group model
var Group = connection.define('group', {
  // Owner Id
  ownerId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  // Group name
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  // Domain
  domain: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  // Topic
  topic: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    validate: {
      len: {
        args: [0, 150],
        msg: 'Topic can not exceed 150 characters.'
      }
    }
  },
  // Access
  private: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
  },
  // Password
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    defaultValue: null,
    validate: {
      // Validate Password
    }
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: false,
  // Timestamps
  timestamps: true,
  // hooks
  hooks: {
    afterValidate: user => {
      if (user.password) {
        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 8);
      }
    }
  }
});

// Relationships
User.belongsToMany(Group, { through: 'UserGroup' });
Group.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'UserGroup' });

// Insert some data by calling sync
connection.sync({
    force: true
}).then ( () => {

  // First user dummy
     User.create( {
         firstName: 'Sam',
         lastName: 'Smith',
         username: 'samsmith',
         email: 'samsith@some.com',
         password: 'somepassword'
    })
    .then(user => {
        user.createGroup({
            ownerId: user.id,
            name: 'Engineering',
            topic: 'A group',
            domain: user.email.split('@')[1],
            private: true,
            password: ''
        });
    });

  // Second user dummy
    User.create( {
        firstName: 'Sam',
        lastName: 'Joshua',
        username: 'samjoshua',
        email: 'samjoshua@gmail.com',
        password: 'somepassword'
 })
 .then(user => {
     user.createGroup({
         ownerId: user.id,
         name: 'Design',
         topic: 'This is some group',
         domain: user.email.split('@')[1],
         private: false,
         password: ''
     });
 });

})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});

export default connection;
```

and the following schema.js file:

```
import {
 GraphQLBoolean,
 GraphQLFloat,
 GraphQLID,
 GraphQLInt,
 GraphQLList,
 GraphQLNonNull,
 GraphQLObjectType,
 GraphQLSchema,
 GraphQLString,
} from 'graphql';

import {
 connectionArgs,
 connectionDefinitions,
 connectionFromArray,
 fromGlobalId,
 globalIdField,
 mutationWithClientMutationId,
 nodeDefinitions,
} from 'graphql-relay';

import db from './database';

/**
* We get the node interface and field from the Relay library.
*
* The first method defines the way we resolve an ID to its object.
* The second defines the way we resolve an object to its GraphQL type.
*/
var {nodeInterface, nodeField} = nodeDefinitions(
(globalId) => {
  var {type, id} = fromGlobalId(globalId);
  if (type === 'User') {
    return db.models.user.getUser(id);
  } else if (type === 'Group') {
    return db.models.group.getGroup(id);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
},
(obj) => {
  if (obj instanceof User) {
    return userType;
  } else if (obj instanceof Group) {
    return groupType;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
);

/**
* We define our own types here.
*/
var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'User',
 description: 'A person who users our app',
 fields: () => ({
   id: globalIdField('User'),
   firstName: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     description: 'A users first name',
     resolve(user) {
       return user.firstName;
     }
   },
   lastName: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve(user) {
       return user.lastName;
     }
   },
   username: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve(user) {
       return user.username;
     }
   },
   email: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve(user) {
       return user.email;
     }
   },
   groups: {
     type: new GraphQLList(groupType),
     resolve(user) {
       return user.getGroups();
     }
   },
 }),
 interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

// Group query
var groupType = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'Group',
 description: 'A users group',
 fields: () => ({
   id: globalIdField('Group'),
   ownerId: {
     type: GraphQLInt,
     resolve(group) {
       return group.ownerId;
     }
   },
   name: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve(group) {
       return group.name;
     }
   },
   topic: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve(group) {
       return group.topic;
     }
   },
   domain: {
     type: GraphQLString,
     resolve(group) {
       return group.domain;
     }
   },
   private: {
     type: GraphQLBoolean,
     resolve(group) {
       return group.private;
     }
   },
   users: {
     type: new GraphQLList(userType),
     resolve(group) {
       return group.getUsers();
     }
   }
 }),
 interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

/**
* This is the type that will be the root of our query,
* and the entry point into our schema.
*/
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'Query',
 description: 'This is the root query',
 fields: () => ({
   node: nodeField,
   // Add our own root fields here
   viewer: {
     type: userType,
     args: {
       id: {
         type: GraphQLInt
       },
       email: {
         type: GraphQLString
       }
     },
     resolve: (root, args) => {
       return db.models.user.findAll({ where: args });
     }
   },
 }),
});

/**
* This is the type that will be the root of our mutations,
* and the entry point into performing writes in our schema.
*/
var mutationType = new GraphQLObjectType({
 name: 'Mutation',
 description: 'Data insertion',
 fields: () => ({
   addUser: {
     type: userType,
     args: {
       firstName: {
         type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
       },
       lastName: {
         type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
       },
       username: {
         type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
       },
       email: {
         type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
       },
       password: {
         type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
       }
     },
     resolve(_, args) {
       return Db.models.user.create({
         firstName: args.firstName,
         lastName: args.lastName,
         username: args.username,
         email: args.email.toLowerCase(),
         password: args.password
       });
     }
   }
 })
});

/**
* Finally, we construct our schema (whose starting query type is the query
* type we defined above) and export it.
*/
export var Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
 query: queryType,
 mutation: mutationType
});
```

I can't seem to find where I have made a mistake. The database file seems fine since I can see the data in the dev table so I guess my error is somewhere in the schema.js file. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Mary, have you gotten anywhere with this?